# Indirect cell reference in Google Sheets with variable input

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a funnel analysis where I can play with the time delay between stages to see the impact. I need my formula to reference 1 row up and X columns over, where X is the number located in column B. This is what I have so far:

`=(INDIRECT("R[-1]C[2]", false))/$C$16)`

Except where you see C[2] - I need the 2 to be a variable fed by a fixed cell reference. I've tried every combination I can think of and have looked at a number of postings on `INDIRECT` cell reference formulas, but this seems to be one step further. It also seems like a fairly common type of "waterfall" analysis, so maybe I need a completely different approach?

Comment: use OFFSET() not INDIRECT().

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample formula:

```
=OFFSET(A2,-1,$B$1)/$C$16
```

Just remember to replace `A2` with the current cell you are entering the formula from, and `$B$1` with the location of the fixed cell reference.

**Reference:**

[OFFSET()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en)